# Folder assistant rules - Handled on the exchange server or on users pc?

Tags: exchange-2016, auto-reply, outlook-2016

So Im wondering if all settings the user sets in folder assistant get send over to the server and is stored there?

Scenario:
User1 is using folder assistant on the public folder "Order" to setup an auto reply whenever someone sends an email to that public folder.

Q: If the user "User1" gets fired, we remove the account/email. Does the rule still apply?

Q: Do user1 need to have outlook opened 24/7 for the rule to apply or does the rule being handled at exchange server and user1's pc can be offline for the duration?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In order to set the public folder assistant rules, user1 must be the Owner of the public folder. When the user mailbox is removed, the rule should still exist and it applies in the server side. You could run the cmdlet below to check.

Get-PublicFolder -Identity   -recurse | format-list Name, HasRules

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/39456dc2-ec51-46f7-b8b2-0840876d3acb/how-can-i-find-all-public-folders-that-have-folder-assistant-rules-that-forward-to-a-distribution?forum=exchange2010